# Looping through multiple rasters using Rasterio to calculate mean

Tags: python, rasterio, rasterstats

I have a folder with a set of three rasters, before, after, and the difference image for each point of observation as shown below. The before and after dates vary for each observation point and represent imagery taken 20 days before and after the event date.

Point_0_after_2021-02-09.tif,
Point_0_before_2021-02-09.tif,
Point_0_difference_2021-02-09.tif

Point_1_after_2021-02-05.tif,
Point_1_before_2021-02-05.tif,
Point_1_difference_2021-02-05.tif

Point_2_after_2021-04-06.tif,
Point_2_before_2021-04-06.tif,
Point_2_difference_2021-04-06.tif

All these images have other bands and indices calculated from Earth Engine. In this study the I want to extract the NDVI band. For the before and after rasters the NDVI band is number 14 and for the difference image, the NDVI band is number 1.

How do I loop through my folder reading the before(B14), after(B14), and the difference(B1) NDVI bands and compute the mean NDVI for each of these raster images in my set and save these values to a CSV or  Excel file?

I am stuck at defining a criteria to select my before, after, and difference images then read the NDVI bands and compute the mean NDVI for each of the rasters.

| observation | Before_NDVI | After_NDVI | Difference_NDVI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Point_0_2021-02-09 | 0.33 | 0.25 | 0.08 |
| Point_1_2021-02-05 | 0.30 | 0.28 | 0.02 |
| Point_2_2021-04-06 | nan | 0.23 | nan |

I have calculated some observations as shown in the table above using the following script working with single rasters;

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
```

```
import os
data_pkg_path = 'data'
swarms_dir = 'swarms'
path = os.path.join(data_pkg_path, swarms_dir, filename)
```

#working with multiple rasters

```
    swarmpoints_path = os.path.join(data_pkg_path, 'swarms')
    all_files = os.listdir(swarmpoints_path)
    print(all_files) 
    before_list = []
for file in all_files:
    search_criteria = "Point_*_before_.tif"
    before = os.path.join(swarmpoints_path, search_criteria)
    #path = os.path.join(swarmpoints_path, file)
    before_list.append(rasterio.open(before))
print(before_list)
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your problem is, at what point in your code are you getting stuck and what are you expecting? That code just looks like it is accessing and creating file paths.

Comment: @GISHuman I have tried editing the question. I am stuck at defining a search criteria that will return 3 new different sets of lists one for the before, after and difference rasters. Once I have these then I can loop through the before, after or difference images while computing the mean NDVI.  Is the question more clear? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code formatting is a mess.  The triple-backtic belongs on a row by itself, once before the code (with an optional "py" formatting indicator), and once after. There are five triple-tics visible right now, and the indenting would not permit execution if you tried.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is how to iterate through the files try this:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

rasterfolder = r'/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/New Folder'

#Add all files to a list
filelist = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(rasterfolder):
    for file in files:
        if 'Point' in file and file.endswith('.tif'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            filelist.append(fullname)

filelist.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.basename(x)) #Sort by filename

#Create a defaultdict(list) with observation as key, and a list of the three files as value
d = defaultdict(list)
for file in filelist:
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0].split('_')
    newname = '_'.join([name[i] for i in [0,1,3]])
    d[newname].append(file)

for observation, filelist in d.items():
    #your code goes here
    print(observation)
    print(filelist)

#Point_0_2021-02-09
#['/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/New Folder/Point_0_after_2021-02-09.tif', '/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/New Folder/Point_0_before_2021-02-09.tif', '/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/New Folder/Point_0_difference_2021-02-09.tif']

#Point_1_2021-02-05
#['/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/New Folder/Point_1_after_2021-02-05.tif', '/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/New Folder/Point_1_before_2021-02-05.tif', '/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/folder/New Folder/Point_1_difference_2021-02-05.tif']
```